# Combinations of elements drawn from sets with non-empty intersections, and limited number of elements can be drawn from each set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have $n$ finite sets. Each set may have non-empty intersections with other sets. Also, for each set, we are allowed only to draw a maximum number of elements, i.e.,

$U=\{ S_1, S_2, ..., S_n \}$

$D = \{ d_1, d_2, ...,d_n \}$

Where $d_i$ denotes the maximum number of elements that are allowed to be drawn from sets $S_i$ and $1 \leq i \leq n$.
If a drawn element, denoted by $x$, belongs to multiple sets (e.g., $x \in S_i$ and $x \in S_j$) then $x$ will be removed from all sets that it belongs to (e.g., $S_i=S_i-\{x\}$ and $S_j=S_j-\{x\}$).

I want to count the combinations of $r$ unordered elements from any sets in $U$ with respect to $D$, where $1 \leq r \leq \sum_{d_i \in D}{d_i}$ .

---

For example, let's say I have the following sets with their $d$ values ([for the visualized version click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBzqG.jpg)).

$_1=\{1,2,3\}$ $\space\space d_1=1$

$_2=\{3,4,5\}$ $\space\space d_2=1$

$_3=\{3,4\}$ $\space\space\space\space\space d_3=2$

For $=1$, we have $5$ unique combinations:

$_1=1\rightarrow C(\{_1\},)=\{(1),(2),(3)\} $

$_2=1\rightarrow C(\{_2\},)=\{(3),(4),(5)\}$

$_3=2\rightarrow C(\{_3\},)=\{(3),(4)\}$

For $=2$, we have $9$ unique combinations:

$_1+_3=3\rightarrow C(\{_1,_3\},)=\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$

$_3=2\rightarrow C(\{_3\},)=\{(3,4)\}$

$_1+_2=2\rightarrow C(\{_1,_2\},)=\{(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5)\}$

$_2+_3=3\rightarrow C(\{_2,_3\},)=\{(3,5),(4,5)\}$

For $=3$, we have $7$ unique combinations:

$_1+_3=3\rightarrow C(\{_1,_3\},)=\{(1,3,4),(2,3,4)\}$

$_2+_3=3\rightarrow C(\{_2,_3\},)=\{(3,4,5)\}$

$_1+_2+_3=4\rightarrow C(\{_1,_2,_3\},)=\{(1,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,3,5),(2,4,5)\}$

For $=4$, we have $2$ unique combinations:

$_1+d_2+_3=4\rightarrow C(\{_1,_2,_3\},)=\{(1,3,4,5),(2,3,4,5)\}$

Comment: It seems to me that your (nice) visualization is not okay for case $r=1$ . There the second $(3)$ should be marked as duplicate (not $(5)$).

Comment: Thank you @drhab I made some corrections. Any thoughts on how to attack this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It comes over to me as complex and I lost courage by examining. I sincerely hope that a blind spot of myself is guilty and that others will be capable to help you.